# Nikola to generate a TOC in static blog

Tags: python, nikola

I am employ [Niloka](https://getnikola.com/handbook.html) to generate a static blog.

Things go smoothly, except that it did not generate a TOC automatically,

I refer the hankbook for "toc" and "content", and thus not find a solution.

Could you please provide any hints?

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but I also think the documentation (or the implementation) of such basic things could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Including the following line in your reStructured Text will insert a table of contents.

```
.. contents::
```

Nikola is extends [reStructuredText](https://getnikola.com/quickstart.html) (reST) which includes two components: its [markup language](https://getnikola.com/quickref.html) and [directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html).

The reST markup language (like Markdown which is used in Stack Overflow) is easy to learn. However, more advanced formatting (like inserting images and table of contents) is accomplished with directives (also part of reST) take option. For example:

```
.. figure:: images/myPic.png
    :width: 200
    :alt: A 3-4-5 triangle
    :align: right
    
    This is the caption for my 3-4-5 triangle.
    Indentation is important.
```